# How to use https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell source code?

Tags: azure

I am new to Windows powershell and Visual Studio. I followed the azure developer guide on github(https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/wiki/Microsoft-Azure-PowerShell-Developer-Guide) till the "Build Solution .Execute tools\Build.ps1" step. Build is failing with 802 errors. How to import the project into visual studio and run the samples? What project is it actually? C# or VB or it just contains cmdlets and sample tests?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the Azure Powershell repository.

Firstly there is the source code, unless you're a developer, or are interested in the inner workings of Azure Powershell, this probably isn't what you are looking for (my apologies if it is!)

As a general overview though, the Build.ps1 configures your machine to build the Azure Powershell cmdlets. The source code is c# and is located [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/tree/dev/src) Build.ps1 installs the following -

- Install [Windows Azure SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/)
- Install [Python 2.7 x86](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3.msi)
- Install [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/)
- Install [Wix 3.8](http://wix.codeplex.com/downloads/get/762937)
- Make sure that git.exe and wix bin folder are in you `PATH` environment variable.
- Set environment variable `EnableNuGetPackageRestore` to value `true`

if you do those things manually, you can then load the project into Visual Studio and compile the cmdlets.

However, the second purpose of that repository is what I suspect you are actually looking for. If you look [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases) you will find the releases of the installers that you can download to install Azure Powershell. Once these are installed on your machine you can browse and configure Azure services via Powershell.

For instance for version [1.0.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v1.0.1-November2015) you will find the download for the latest version of Azure Powershell (at the time of writing anyway!)

If you are just looking to learn Powershell and Azure then that is probably the place you want to start.

If you are looking to explore the source code, then that is there also.

Comment: Hi @Micheal B. Thanks a ton for the reply. This cleared some confusion.The main reason I want to explore azure powershell is to automate VM creation using powershell commands using java project. Before exploring github powershell, i have download the azure powershell and able to login to my subscription and an AD app for authentication/authorization and was able to execute the create vm command(using resource manager cmds). Next I am looking to integrate/automate this approach with a java project. In this respect, can I use the github repo? If yes, what is the area of code I should look into?

Comment: That's probably a question on its own! but you could probably start looking at the [xplat](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli) tools, which is the cross platform version of Azure Powershell, written in Nodejs